# prevent IconMenuIcon from being highlighted when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, selected

I am using html, javascript and the dojo library.

What I have is a IconMenu with 6 IconMenuItems.
Now, whenever I click a IconMenuIcon it gets highlighted but I want to prevent the highlighting effect.
IconMenuIcon has the property "selected" which gets set to "true" on the click event and I think this is the cause of the highlighting.

**I now tried to do the following on every "on" function (onclick, onmouseover etc) dojo offers:**

> this.set("selected", false);

unfortunately the IconMenuItem still gets highlighted -.-

EDIT: here is the code of the widget:

http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojox/trunk/mobile/IconMenuItem.js

It has this propertie:

> selColor: "mblIconMenuItemSel"

how can I set it to luicid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the kind people in the official dojo irc I came to this simple piece of javascript.
The ItemMenuItem has a property which determines the highlighting color:

> dojo.ready(function(){
>       // logic that is executed when dojo is ready goes here
>       alert("dojo.ready");
>
> var portalButton1 = dijit.byId("portalButton1");
>     portalButton1.set("selColor", "RED");
>
> });

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used dojo but I would of thought the highlighting was done with CSS, have a look at the classes applied to the "selected" element and see if it matches a highlight styling and edit as you need.

Comment: please be more specific. I am currently trying to solve the problem with CSS but with no luck.

selected isn t known by CSS.

Comment: Sorry, What I meant was that if the code is just adding a class to your menuItems and then using the css to style the currently selected node then you could "hijack" the styling and implement your own. If however it is adding the styling directly to the html inline you will need to find where this is added and either remove it or change it to what you need, without seeing the resulting HTML or _itemBase all I can do it theorise what your problem could be.